# Improvement in SQL Query - Access - Join / IN / Exists

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my SQL Query - using in Access. It is providing the desired result.
But just wanted opinion whether the approach is correct. 
How can this be speeded up.

```
    SELECT INVDETAILS2.F5
           , INVDETAILS2.F16
           , ExpectedResult.DLID
           , ExpectedResult.NumRows
    FROM INVDETAILS2
   INNER
    JOIN (INVDL INNER JOIN ExpectedResult ON INVDL.DLID =ExpectedResult.DLID)
               ON (INVDETAILS2.F14 = ROUND(ExpectedResult.Total))
               AND (INVDETAILS2.F1 = INVDL.RegionCode)
    WHERE INVDETAILS2.F29 ='2013-03-06'
      AND INVDETAILS2.F5 IN (SELECT INVDETAILS2.F5 
                               FROM (ExpectedResult
                                      INNER JOIN INVDL
                                      ON ExpectedResult.DLID = INVDL.DLID)
                         INNER JOIN INVDETAILS2
                                    ON INVDL.RegionCode = INVDETAILS2.F1
                                    AND round(ExpectedResult.Total)
                                        = INVDETAILS2.F14
                              WHERE INVDETAILS2.F29='2013-03-06'
                              GROUP BY INVDETAILS2.F5 
                              HAVING Count(ExpectedResult.DLID)<2
                            )
    ;
```

Approximate Number of Rows in 
"ExpectedResult" - Millions
"INVDL" - 80,000
"INVDETAILS" - 300,000 - Total , For One Date - approx - 10,000 , then again lesser for each region per date.

Please provide a better query if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you could investigate that might help speed things up:

**Indexing**

Make sure that you have indexed all of the columns involved in JOINs, WHERE clauses, and GROUP BY clauses.

**JOIN expressions involving functions**

A couple of your JOINs use `Round(ExpectedResult.Total)`, so if you have an index on `ExpectedResult.Total` your query won't be able to use it. You may get a performance boost if you add a `RoundedTotal` column (Long Integer, Indexed), populate it with

```
UPDATE [ExpectedResult] SET [RoundedTotal]=Round([Total])
```

and then use the `RoundedTotal` column in your JOINs.

Comment: thanks. the conditions in the first select for join and in the second select for the join are same. thats why was wondering if anything should / can be done.